# Weird UIKeyboard Appearance in ios 9.2 - Shift, backspace, and keyboard buttons turn black

Tags: ios, keyboard, uikeyboard

Some of my users are reporting a weird issue with the keyboard where some of the buttons turn completely black (see pic below). I am setting the keyboard to the dark keyboard in the AppDelegate of my app and all of the text fields are set to use the default keyboard style. Has anyone else experienced this? Is it an iOS issue or something else within my app?

[image: black buttons]

**Edit:**

This doesn't always happen. Only randomly. Here are my keyboard settings for this field (all other text fields match these settings):

[image]

Comment: Could you post some more keyboard settings from your interface builder? I can't reproduce this simply by setting the keyboard to dark. The keys appear dark, not white like in your picture.

Comment: I addd it to the original post.  Unfortunately, it only happens randomly so I don't have exact steps to reproduce.

Comment: Did you fins a solution? Same happens for me.

Comment: I didn't find a 'for sure fix' for it, but I did change the keyboard type from "default" to "numbers and punctuation" and it hasn't happened since.

Comment: @Arc676 you can repro on a UITextView with keyboardAppearance set to .Dark, then present a image picker view and come back. I'm also wondering if there's a solution to this. Seems like an iOS bug...

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: No, I didn't. I actually haven't seen the issue since.